# Query in DocumentDB for Searching

Tags: c#, search, azure-cosmosdb

I have a documents something like

```
{ id : "123", name : "sai", marks : {English : 50, Maths : 60, Science :90} }
```

marks may contain any no of subjects and with any name. (schema is not fixed)

I want the list of students who failed in any one subject (<35 in any subject)

Is there any method to do this or need to change schema to get the results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looking at this now, just a question - under marks, do you always have "subject":"name" and then the mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with a slight modification to your schema my document now looks like this -

```
{id :  "123", name :  "sai", marks : [
        {Subject :  "English", Grade :  50},
        {Subject :  "Maths", Grade :  60},
        {Subject :  "Science", Grade :  90}
    ]
}
```

Then a custom IndexingPolicy IncludePath has to be added that allows for Range queries like this -

```
    {
        Path :  /"marks"/[]/"Grade"/?,
        IndexType :  Range,
        NumericPrecision :  3
    }
```

Once this is in place, you can run the following query

```
    SELECT VALUE students FROM students JOIN marks IN students.marks WHERE marks.Grade < 60
```

If you wanted to do this in .NET with LINQ then let me know and I will post the LINQ for this query.

If you don't add the RANGE index on the Grade field you could still do this query but you would have to specify the "Allow Scan in Query" option which would force a scan. Not great for performance, this way is much better.

If you can't change your schema to what I have, then let me know and I will play a bit more with the query